# Eclipse mars compact ui

Tags: eclipse

```
Environment: 
  Eclipse Mars 64 Bit, 
  Fedora Linux 21 64 Bit
```

So far i was using eclipse luna and using steps in

http://fbksoft.com/6-tips-to-make-eclipse-lighter-prettier-and-more-efficient/

to make the user interface appear at a reduced size. It works great.

However, with the newly released Eclipse Mars version, those steps (i.e. using gtkrc file) is no longer working.

I would be deeply indebted if anyone found a way to reduce the UI interface size (with eclipse mars version) and let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

add this line to your script to launch eclipse:
`export SWT_GTK3=0`

Comment: Thanks. Sure, will try and let you know.

Comment: if you have problems, I can send you my files